# Text file string removal/replacement with Windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to remove exactly three numbers after dot or if its easier everything after **`.`** and before **`;`** using a Windows batch script.

**Before**

> ABC;CDEF;GH;123:456.XXX;EFG;789:123.XXX
> ABC;CDEF;GH;123:456.XXX;EFG;789:123.XXX
> ...

**After**

> ABC;CDEF;GH;123:456;EFG;789:123
> ABC;CDEF;GH;123:456;EFG;789:123
> ...

I've been trying something with `myVar:~0,-4` but I don't know how to use it when replacing with other string:

```
set "str=;"
for /f "tokens=* delims=." %%A in (%input%) do set myVar=%%A & echo !myVar:%myVar:~0,-4%=%str%! >> %output%
```

Comment: does the strings actually contain the asterisks?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard I'd say it's an attempt to make the `.xxx` bold

Comment: @Magoo That is what I thought as well.

Comment: good thinking @Magoo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your examples this method doesn't need to know the token count.

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Copy/Y "input.txt" "output.txt">Nul
(For /F "UseBackQDelims=" %%A In ("output.txt") Do (Set "OL="
    For %%B In (%%A) Do Set "OL=!OL!;%%~nB"
    Echo=!OL:~1!))>"input.txt"
::Del "output.txt"
Pause
```

If you're happy with the content of `input.txt` you may remove the first two characters, **`::`** from `line 7`. If not, don't worry nothing is lost, you can delete `input.txt` and rename `output.txt` to `input.txt`.

*I have used `input.txt` and `output.txt`, please adjust those two names as necessary*

Comment: Good trick! Using `%%~nB` to eliminate the "extension". **`:)`** +1

Comment: i like your solution and it does remove .XXX. But i also have same spaces in ABC, CDEF part of the line and now they are replaced with ;

Comment: My working solution was designed to suit your question. Did you expect everyone to guess that your text file content wasn't pertinent to your real world issue?

Comment: @lalluvia `delims=;` should cure that.

Comment: @Compo my mistake, didn't realize spaces would be a problem

Comment: la lluvia, because your original question, _(including file content)_, was answered by 3 respondents, the appropriate fix would be to roll back your new edit, _(I've already done that for you)_, and choose an accepted answer. Then create a new question with the updated file content, referencing this one if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

```
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=." %%A in (%input%) do set "myVar1=%%A"&set "myVar2=%%B"&set "myVar3=%%C" & echo !myVar1!!myVar2:~3!!myVar3:~3! >> %output%
```

or

```
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=." %%A in (%input%) do set "myVar2=%%B"&set "myVar3=%%C" & echo %%A!myVar2:~3!!myVar3:~3! >> %output%
```

would be my first attempt - assuming your structure contains exactly 2 `.`s which are each followed by 3 characters to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

This method works with any number of dots placed at any positions:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Get file lines
(for /F "delims=" %%a in (input.txt) do (

   rem Split line at dots
   set "line=%%a"
   set "myVar="
   for %%b in ("!line:.=" "!") do (

      if not defined myVar (
         rem Copy first part
         set "myVar=%%~b"
      ) else (
         rem Eliminate first three chars from rest of parts
         set "part=%%~b"
         set "myVar=!myVar!!part:~3!"
      )

   )
   echo !myVar!

)) > output.txt
```